# Territory restrictions and linked tracks in Spotify

Tags: spotify

I am building an app that needs to know if a track is playable in the user's region.

It's easy to check the basic territorial restrictions of a track using the Metadata API. However, I am encountering tracks that the Metadata API says are out of my region, but are auto-linked to versions of the same track that aren't region locked. ie. Metadata says I can't play a track, but as far as the user is concerned, Spotify can play that track.

Here's an example:

'Sweet Unrest' by Apparat @ spotify:track:4H4h3ulzjGVox14GHiCEoo

I am in the UK (territory code GB)

The lookup link is http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/.json?uri=spotify:track:4H4h3ulzjGVox14GHiCEoo

There is no GB code in the resulting territories string, so in theory, I should not be able to play the track. However, in the main Spotify player, I can see that it is auto linked to [spotify:track:11S6TQybYumAnNApugZWSJ](http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/.json?uri=spotify%3atrack:11S6TQybYumAnNApugZWSJ) which is playable in my region. If I paste the supposedly unplayable track's URI into the top left Spotify search box, it plays.

Is there an API based way to check for tracks like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, not at this time. The linking is actually done by the client itself rather than any of our backend services, so none of our APIs have this information.

Comment: OK, thanks. There isn't an API player event which fires if a track is unplayable, is there?

Comment: In the Spotify Apps API? You could add an observer for models.EVENT.CHANGE on the player then watch the playing property, I guess. Seems a bit hacky, mind.

Comment: Yeah, at that point I start a 2 second timer (to allow for network lag), if it isn't playing when the time is up, I assume it has failed and move on. Also, the player sometimes fails on legit tracks that have worked a few minutes before (Spotify pops up a 'Track Not Found' yellow status bar message). Would be nice to have a failed event with some sort of description or error code attached

Answer (score 2):

You can detect whether a track is playable or not using an undocumented property of each track: data.availableForPlayback

```
Track.fromURI("spotify:track:XXX", function(track) {
alert(track.data.availableForPlayback);
});
```

If you run the code above, you should get a True/False that does what you're after.

Comment: Cannot find `track.data.availableForPlayback`. However, there is a property `track.available` which seems to provide the same information.